# Calculate object rotation from camera view change

Tags: javascript, jquery, camera

I need to calculate the rotation of an object in 3D space. I'm attempting to use [threejs](http://threejs.org/docs/), but haven't been able to figure it out.
What I need is:(rotationX, rotationY, rotationZ), in degrees.

I have the beginning camera view:
(position[x,y,z], target[x,y,z], up[x,y,z])

and the ending camera view:
(position[x,y,z], target[x,y,z], up[x,y,z])

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this right now and I have no experience with three.js, but the logic should be something like:

```
var m1 = new THREE.Matrix4();
m1.lookAt(pos1, tar1, up1);
var q1 = new THREE.Quaternion();
q1.setFromRotationMatrix(m1);

var m2 = new THREE.Matrix4();
m2.lookAt(pos2, tar2, up2);
var q2 = new THREE.Quaternion();
q2.setFromRotationMatrix(m2);


q1.inverse();
var q3 = q2.multiply(q1);


var a = new THREE.Euler();
a.setFromQuaternion(q3, 'XYZ');
```

The method here is just getting two Quaternions representing the objects rotation.  This can also be fetched directly from the object with .quaternion()
Since:

```
QStart * QTransition = QResult
```

leads to

```
QTransition = QResult * inverse(QStart)
```

Comment: This is helpful, but I'm still not seeing consistent values. A couple notes: 
"q1.setFromRotationMatrix();" should be "q1.setFromRotationMatrix(m1);" and "lookat" should be "lookAt".

Comment: I updated the answer now. How is the result coming out? I'm uncertain about which way the multiply function works. You could try swapping q1 and q2

Comment: I think you need to swap to var q3 = q2.multiply(q1);

Comment: Changed that now. Did that give more sensible results?